# Длинный прыжок asm

Tags: ассемблер

Имеется инструкция `jmp qword ptr gs:[0xa28]` по адресу `00007FF9E238C250`. Значение `gs` равно `0x2B`. Отладчик показал, что прыжок ведёт на адрес `000000005FAD7EF0`. Вопрос: как вычисляется этот адрес? Как перенаправить этот прыжок на другой адрес или сделать far `call`?

Comment: Это надо ваш отладчик смотреть, какие именно адреса он показывает. Вообще, если вас интересует например абсолютный адрес, то берется база из 5 элемента глобальной дескрипторной таблицы (на который указывает ваш gs) и к ней прибавляется смещение 0xa28 ... заменить ... посмотреть что вообще описывает селектор в gs, какого оно размера и относительно начала этого сегмента брать нужный адрес, а jmp на call меняется изменением кода инструкции, который там первым байтом идет (может не только первый затронуть, смотреть надо)

Comment: Как перенаправить - вопрос интересный. Три варианта точно. 1. вписать другую инструкцию. 2. Поменять адрес с которого берётся адрес прыжка (т.е. само 0xa28).  3. Поменять адрес прыжка по приведённому адресу `gs:0xa28`